# Animating A popup Window

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to add a popup window by adding the view as a subview, I have my Container View which is a UIView.  The "sus" is my UIViewController that presents the user with several options.  However when I run this code, the View just appears, no Flip animation.  Any Ideas?

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("flip");
UIView.SetAnimationDuration(1);
UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromLeft, Container, true);
Container.AddSubview(sus.View);
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to this

```
UIView.Animate(1,0,UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft,() => 
                      {
            Container.AddSubview(sus.View);
        },() => {});
```

use the [Samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples) by xamarin, it contains almost anything

Comment: Hmm, no dice, it just presents it, without the transition.  I don't know if it helps but, I have a Login screen that is a UIView Controller, and I added the containerview as a subview to the Loginscreen, then Called that UIView.Animate exactly as you coded it, and it just presents the view without any animation, any other ideas?

Comment: Where did you find that particular example?  I found the CATransitions, but not the UIView Transitions.

Comment: try to add the subview before the animate and set hidden to true and then in the animate change it to true.. i'm not sure but this maybe can work

Comment: Hmm, gave that a go and still no dice, however I do get that affect if I flip the whole screen instead of just a small screen.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I am also overlaying the entire screen with a view to darken it, perhaps adding that view first and then overlaying the other view on top is causing the issue?